# python take single argument input which can be two different types

Tags: python

I am in a situation where I am accepting a user input, that can either be `True` or `False` or a `string`.

I know i can just take input as string then parse it to `boolean` if its either `true` or `false`, but is there a better way to parse input as either `string` or `boolean`?

```
parser.add_argument('--s', type=int, default=False)
```

thank you.

Comment: What is parser? And it does not make much sense for something to be string or boolean. Types are usually defined to be one type, so you could have the input be a string as empty or `None` to denote the variable as being "False" or filled with what the value should be if entered when "True".

Comment: How would you want to use it?

Comment: If you are using argparse, you can pass a callable as the `type` argument, and convert the input however you like. The input type is always a string. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can do this pretty easily.

```
value = arg == "true" if arg in ("true", "false") else arg
```

Assuming you want to accept true/false in arbitrary case, it's only marginally more complicated:

```
value = arg.lower() == "true" if arg.lower() in ("true", "false") else arg
```

This potentially runs `lower()` twice, so if that's a concern, you could cache that value first. Though in an argument parser I doubt it would be.

Really, though, I think it's more likely you should be accepting two different arguments. Mixing types like this is a bad sign and makes it harder to end up with easily readable, debuggable code.